# System of linear equations with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am taking some online linear algebra classes.
I would like to understand how to solve this system of linear equations.
I used GEM to go to this step:

$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\0 & 9 & 13& 9\end{pmatrix}$

How should I choose the pivots? and what about the following steps?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on your notation but will assume that the first three columns are the LHS of the equations you were given and the fourth is the RHS.

The pivot elements are those which are the first non-zero element in a row: so, the $1$ and the first $9$.  The columns containing these elements are the pivot columns; the other columns on the LHS are non-pivot columns.  If you assign a parameter to each variable corresponding to a non-pivot column then you can solve for the others.  So, if your variables are $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in that order, then you can let $x_3=t$, then rewrite the rows of the matrix as equations and solve for $x_2$ and $x_1$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't understand which equations I am supposed to solve for x2 and x1 in terms of s and t?

Comment: So what would be the solutions in this case? I'm not sure to understand.